# How do you prove this implication using its contrapositive?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value

$∀x∈R,|2x-1|≤5$ and $|2x-1|>3⇒(x^4+7≤7x^2 )$  or $(2x^3≥8x+5)$

This is what I got for the contrapositive:

$∀x∈R,(x^4+7>7x^2 )$  and $(2x^3<8x+5)⇒|2x-1|>5$ or $|2x-1|≤3$

Where would I go from here? How would I combine the 'and' logical connective?

Comment: I don't believe you need to change "for all" to "there exists". Other than that, this looks correct.

Comment: Now that you have the correct contrapositive statement, the next step is to prove it. That it, you must show that any value of $x$ which satisfies both of the polynomial inequalities must also satisfies at least one of the absolute value inequalities.

Comment: How would you combine the statements between the "and" operator?